# Laravel - Resource route passing in wrong parametre (not the id)

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have an issue with my the update method in my controller.

Normally everything works and it takes care of itself, but this time its not working.

My controller:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, Vehicle::$rules, Vehicle::$messages);

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        $this->vehicle->update($id, $input);
        return Redirect::route('admin.vehicles.index')->with('success', 'Car Updated');
    }

    return Redirect::back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation);
}
```

Repository:

```
public function update($id, $input)
{
    print_r($id);
    die();
}
```

This prints out:

```
{vehicle}
```

from the URI:

```
http://localhost/admin/vehicles/1/edit
```

My form:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'admin.vehicles.update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal edit-vehicle-form', 'method' => 'PATCH']) }}

    // inputs

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::submit('Update Vehicle', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) }}
    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('/admin/vehicles', 'VehiclesController');
```

Where is this going wrong? How can I get this form to send the ID not the word vehicle?

Comment: what is in your routes file for this route?

Comment: Isn't "vehicle" the Model? Laravel fetches it from the db for you.

Comment: Otherwise try to use 'to' => '\Admin\VehiclesController@update'

Comment: Actually you may be right, other it would be pulling vehicles from the URL not the singular. I had another issue which I thought was caused by this but maybe not! Thanks.